# Cannot switch to AHCI Constant RST error when trying to reinstall. Not running windows

Tags: system-installation

Currently struggling to reinstall the latest ubuntu on this laptop, and for whatever reason it keeps giving me a disable rst during the install. I went to the BIOS but there is no setting for it.

The laptop is an HP Pavillion 15

Comment: Can you expand on "this laptop"? What brand and model is it? Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? This information may make it easier for someone to provide specific suggestions 

Comment: The laptop is a Hp pavillion-15 ubuntu 20.04 is the version we trying to install and the version is 19.04